# indigo desktop-full

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I don't find what is missing to the indigo packages to be able to get the desktop-full. At this time, indigo gets 368 packages and hydro 1260. But I think that when we install hydro-desktop-full, not all of them are installed. Am I wrong ?

So my question is: where can I find the list of packages needed to have the desktop-full (and so what is needed to add from source) ?

Thanks

Configuration: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr / indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158966/indigo-desktop-full/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see http://answers.ros.org/question/154806/indigo-on-trusty/

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1